# Play + scala + MySQL

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, anorm

I'm starting develop with Play 2.2.1 and Scala 2.10.2. I'm developing a CRUD application. I'm following a example from book "Play for Scala: Covers 2", but I've a problem.

In these book there is this code in model

```
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.db.DB

def getAll: List[Product] = DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
sql().map
  ( row =>
      Product(row[Long]("id"), row[Long]("ean"), row[String]("name"), row[String]("description"))
  ).toList
}
```

But when I try run it, I recieve this error:

```
    value map is not a member of anorm.SqlQuery
```

Why doesn't function .map?

Thanks you!

Comment: LimbSoup's answer is definitely the way to go, but you may have needed an extra (), as in `SQL("select ...")().map` to make the example work.

Comment: Do any of these responses answer your question? If so, you should accept one as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`SqlQuery` doesn't have a `map` function. I'm not sure how the example in the book is supposed to look, but I'm a little wary of it if it's using that clunky syntax for anorm. I think it should always be preferred to use result set parsers defined separately from the function itself--as you'll be able to reuse them elsewhere.

```
import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.db.DB

case class Product(id: Long, ean: Long, name: String, description: String)

object Product {

    /** Describes how to transform a result row to a `Product`. */
    val parser: RowParser[Product] = {
        get[Long]("products.id") ~ 
        get[Long]("products.ean") ~ 
        get[String]("products.name") ~ 
        get[String]("products.description") map {
            case id ~ ean ~ name ~ description => Product(id, ean, name, description)
    }

    def getAll: List[Product] = {
        DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
            SQL("SELECT * FROM products").as(parser *)
        }
    }
}
```

I've made the assumption that your table is named `products`. It's best to use the full column names in parsers (`products.id` instead of `id`), as if later you need to combine parsers (using joined results), then anorm won't get confused from multiple tables using a similar column name like `id`. The `getAll` function now looks so much cleaner, and we can re-use the parser for other functions:

```
def getById(id: Long): Option[Product] = {
    DB.withConnection{ implicit connection =>
        SQL("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = {id}")
            .on("id" -> id)
            .as(parser.singleOpt)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial it is mentioned that,

**Before we can get any results, we have to create a query. With Anorm, you call
`anorm.SQL` with your query as a String parameter**:

```
import anorm.SQL
import anorm.SqlQuery
val sql: SqlQuery = SQL("select * from products order by name asc")
```

Is this missing from your code?.

Comment: Yes I've used: `import anorm.SQL` and `import anorm.SqlQuery` but nothing :(

Comment: did you declared the sql query?

Answer (score 0):

SqlQuery is being made private (pending PR), so it should not be used directly. In place SQL("...") or SQL"..." functions can be used, in a safer way.

Best

Comment: The OP wasn't really trying to use `SqlQuery` directly. `SQL(..)` just returns that type.